# Why does curl_exec() return partial HTML from one URL and full (as expected) HTML on others?

Tags: php

Compare the following two chunks of code using two values for $url:

1)

```
$url = 'http://www.localharvest.org';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
echo htmlspecialchars(curl_exec($ch));
```

2)

```
$url = 'http://www.localharvest.org/caledonia-farm-M136';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
echo htmlspecialchars(curl_exec($ch));
```

1 returns full HTML as expected. 2 only returns a single line of HTML. Visiting the second page confirms there is in fact much more HTML.

Why?
<3

Comment: What do you missing? In the second url i see a lot of JS generated html chunk if i am right.

Comment: What does the single line of HTML look like?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this.

I got the same result. It **might** be because of the way Curl looks for the headers. Headers are usually seperated from the main content by 4 new lines.

If you look at the content of the second URL you will see that rather fantastically there is a lot of white space around the line:

```
 <!--jsp:setProperty name="mapg" property="projection" value="init"/-->
```

Curl **might** be getting confused as to what is body and what is header.

I suggest you use some different options to see what Curl is **actually** getting back, try `CURLOPT_HEADER`

[Full list of PHP Curl options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: After taking a look at the headers I found these differences: 
With URL 1: 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=6FE45F199936F288EA3F75D97B0D4970; Path=/ Powered-By-ChinaCache: MISS from CMN-NJ-2-35e Switch: FSCS 

========================================

With URL 2: 
Content-Length: 136 Age: 5716 Powered-By-ChinaCache: HIT from CMN-NJ-2-35c Switch: FSCS They both returned HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Comment: That doesn't help much. Hmm. Have you tried `file_get_contents()` - I know that is not an ideal solution - but it might get you somewhere